# Css bundling and Minification, css rule contains absolute urls

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

I have defined some font `CSS` rule which has absolute urls like

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Oxygen';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    src: local('Oxygen Bold'), local('Oxygen-Bold'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/oxygen/v2/yVHpdQrmTj9Kax1tmFSx2j8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff) format('woff');
}
```

but when I do the bundling with absolute URLs. I hit the 400 exception as it's unable to resolve the path.

> "NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - Something/Content/css/http:/themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/oxygen/v2/RzoNiRR1p2Mqyyz2RwqSMw.woff"
>       RzoNiR...Mw.woff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to customize `CssRewriteUrlTransform` and ignore paths that start with `https://` and `http://`